# After changing css, hover doesn't work

Tags: jquery

After running this: `$('.bar').css({'color':'#fff'});` hover for .bar stops working. Why?

Also, `$('.bar:hover').css({'color':'#fff'});` doesn't change hover's color too, why? What am I missing?

http://jsfiddle.net/hh4NJ/

Comment: Possibly because the hover state is a pseudo class, so when you change the value for `.bar` it changes it for `.bar:hover` as well.

Comment: `$('.bar:hover')` isn't a standard jQuery selector, is this implemented by a plugin?

Comment: Have you tried with ...css("color", "#fff") instead of using the pair value? If you use the pair value perhaps it changes the whole css, meanwhile if you just do it in a non pair-value way, you just change that css value.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You haven't defined what you mean by "hover", but if you're talking about CSS `:hover`, then it's because inline styles (as set by `.css()` override stylesheet styles.

You can add `!important` to your CSS definition to override the inline.

```
.bar:hover {
    color: #ABCDEF !important;
}
```

I don't believe this works with older IE though.

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/hh4NJ/1/

---

Another *(and arguably better)* solution would be to use `.addClass()` instead of `.css()` to change the style. Then you can take care of all of it in your CSS *(except for adding/removing the class of course)*.

```
$('.bar').addClass('whiteColor');
```

```
.whiteColor {
    color:#fff;
}
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/hh4NJ/2/

---

Regarding your update, you can't use pseudo selectors like `:hover` for DOM selection.

Comment: But why does jquery overwrite the hover event? I understand the priority of inline over external, but that only applies when there is a conflict of styling.

Answer (score 2):

In the [cascade](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/cascade.html#cascade), rules in the style attribute will beat rules applied with a selector.

The jQuery `css` method modifies the style attribute.

Keep your CSS and JS separate. Use JS to edit add and remove *classes* from the HTML, and apply your CSS using a class selector. (Make sure that the `:hover` rule still has a [specific](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/cascade.html#specificity) enough selector though).

As a quick and *dirty* solution, you can also make your `:hover` rules [`!important`](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/cascade.html#important-rules), but [you shouldn't](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3706819/what-are-the-implications-of-using-important-in-css).

> Also, `$('.bar:hover').css({'color':'#fff'});` doesn't change hover's color too, why?

jQuery's selector engine matches elements, it doesn't modify the stylesheet. If this was supported then you would be saying "At the time this code executes, make the .bar I am pointing to white" not "When I point at a .bar, make it white".